# how to prevent duplicated rows in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

now i am working with three tables,A,B and C:

A table structure:
ID,
Name,
Age

B table structure:
ID,
A.ID-> foreign key,
Hospital Name

C table structure:
ID,
A.ID->foreign key,
Drug Name

so the relation between A and B is one to many and also the same with A and C

when i make any query to find how many persons in my database i found duplicated rows
actually its not duplicated but it has for example 2 rows with the child table like: the one person has 2 records in table B so the result doesn't reflect the actual number of matched record because its linked with child tables .

**Question is :** how to prevent duplication in case like that?

Comment: If you just want people, why do you need the link? If you need a hospital as well, is the any way to decide which hospital, because if there is not, how can you have one row?

Comment: i am doing that for search among people who has specific criteria so the same one can be registerd  in two hospital but actually he is only one i need to see that person one time not many and i made link to see have the applity to search by hospital too

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct or a subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.Name
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.ID = b.aID
WHERE b.Hospital = 123
```

Or

```
WHERE b.Hospital IN ( 123, 456 )
```

Also

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name
FROM a
INNER JOIN (SELECT aID, Hospital FROM b) x
ON a.ID = x.aID
WHERE x.Hospital - 123
```

And

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name
FROM a
WHERE a.ID 
IN ((SELECT aID FROM b WHERE Hospital = 123))
```

Comment: i don't want to use where clause i am using filter for the form depending in the user needs so how to avoid duplication

Comment: What is the Record Source of your form?

Comment: the record source is another form that has all data fields and childs tables linked with it

Comment: What comes immediately after Record Source on the property sheet in design view of the form you want to filter?

Comment: in the design view its empty so i have some textboxes to allow user to search with any criteria

Comment: If the user is searching with any criteria, how are you presenting the data that is found?

Comment: as rows in the datasheet view like this  http://www.learnaccessnow.com/figs/fig0103.jpg

Comment: That is a table. How are you processing the information to create a filtered list? How are you getting even the rows with duplicates?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10389/discussion-between-remou-and-special-life)